# Nginx show 404 if URL end with extension ( ttf | mp3 | mp4 | webm | ogg | jpg | jpeg | gif | ico | css | js )

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Issue with Nginx Url rewrite , it show's `404` if `URl's` end on any of these

```
 ( ttf | mp3 | mp4 | webm | ogg | jpg | jpeg | gif | ico | css | js )
```

**Example URL** .

```
example.com/convert-to-ttf
example.com/convert-to-jpeg
example.com/convert-to-jpg
example.com/convert-to-mp4
```

but if if add / in end of URL then it works . anyone know what is the issue

Comment: Could you post your config? Do you  proxy your requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the config file.

```
   location ~* .(ttf|mp3|mp4|webm|ogg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    .....
   }
```

changed it to:

```
   location ~* \.(ttf|mp3|mp4|webm|ogg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    ...
   }
```

Now its work fine with ends in one of those strings.